# How to administer out-of-domain Windows Server 2008 Core remotely?

Tags: windows, remote, windows-server-core

I have set up a Windows Server 2008 Core Edition, with a local administrator account only. I have set up (I think) remote connection and remote administration (following [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.geekofalltrades.aspx)).

I have set up RSAT on my Windows 7 Professional desktop, and i am logged with a local administrator account.

Remote desktop works all right, but I cannot get to use most of the administration tools:

- I have access to Services and can stop/start services remotely.
- I have access to the Task Manager.
- I cannot use the Disk Manager (complains about access rights).
- I cannot use the Users and Local Groups (access denied).
- I cannot use the Device Manager (access denied).

I tried [establishing a remote smb connection](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/breves/win_remote_admin_tools.html.fr) using `net use \\`*`server_name`*`\IPC$ /u:Administrator *`, to no avail.

Any idea ?

Comment: you could consider learning to use the command line tools ;-) to do what you need: net user or net group (user management), diskpart/defrag (disk management), pnputil/devcon (devcon is not installed by default, see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx ) for device management.

Comment: I clearly intend to do that. But RSAT would be very useful anyway, if only to check that my configuration is valid...

Answer (score 2):

I had to play with cmdkey a bit with my out-of-domain Hyper-V server (which is a server core-based OS)

Try`cmdkey /list:servername`to see what you're authenticating to your server core machine as.

If you don't like it, then you can change it with`cmdkey /add:servername /user:administrator /pass:password`and force your connection to the right username/password combination.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Start with: do not run server core without a domain. Bad idea to start with.

Keeping local Admin passwords in sync on both machiens may help - that way authentication should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Core Configurator](http://coreconfig.codeplex.com/) for all of my Hyper-V Servers, which are all just windows core with the hyper-v role installed. It seems to be pretty nice for a lot of the day to day stuff.